# Main thread does not seem to be interrupted

Tags: java, multithreading

in my Java program main thread does not get interrupted. Why?

```
/*
* This class counts till infinity
*/
class infinityT extends Thread{
  int counter = 0;
  public void run(){
    try{
      while(true){
         if(counter>500){
           // this class will throw compilation error here as Thread.sleep is not a valid method here as it does not extend Thread class
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
        System.out.println(counter++);
      } 
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
      System.out.println("infinity Interrupted: "+counter);
    }
  }
}

class interruption{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Thread t = new Thread(new infinityT());

    // start the thread
    t.start();

    try{
      // main thread does not seem to interrupt
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
      System.out.println("Main thread interrupted!");
    }

    t.interrupt();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
...
...
499
500
infinity Interrupted: 501
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Code makes no sense to me.

Comment: you never know the order in which the threads are scheduled. So when you started the thread t, the main thread might have been put to background, so you never saw the interruption on the main thread. Try to run the program multiple times to see the differences.

Comment: @Fildor: it's just a demo program and counts till infinity if not interrupted

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla: but if the main thread was interrupted so I should get the output of interrupted main, right?

Comment: main thread gets interrupted, you might have missed it among the other outputs. check carefully and if u execute the same program multiple times, see the position in which the Main thread gets interrupted.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. Please post your comment as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main thread gets interrupted, you might have missed it among the other outputs. check carefully and if u execute the same program multiple times, see the position in which the Main thread gets interrupted

Answer (score 2):

Your *main* thread does get *interrupted* but what it doesn't do is *sleep* when you call *Thread.sleep()* because you've already set its *interrupted* flag. Hence, all or most of the numbers would get printed after the *Main thread interrupted!* message.

If you scroll up the console (you may have to increase its buffer or just reduce the loop count to 10 or something) you should see it getting printed as well.

As an aside, you do not need to extend `Thread` to call `sleep()` as it's a *static* method. Or, you can simply start `infinityT` directly instead of passing it as `Runnable` again.